# Get the ComboBox selected item in ComboBox_SelectionChanged method

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am following the MVVM pattern with C# and WPF. In my .xaml.cs file, I have a  `combobox_SelectionChanged` method where I need to access the selected item of the `ComboBox`.

```
var cb=sender as ComboBox;
Type t=cd.getType();
```

I tried to get the type and then the object bound to `SelectedItem` property. That was not successful.

Then I tried the following.

```
ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)cb.SelectedItem;
string text = cbi.Content.ToString();
```

even that was not successful. Can someone suggest me a way to do that ?

Comment: You should use some binding instead of accessing to the data like this when you follow a MVVM pattern.

Comment: But it's not possible to use Command attribute with Combobox. Like we do with checkboxes. If there was the Command attribute for Comboboxes, then this would have been easire

Comment: Do you need to perform some actions when the selected item change or you just need to retrieve the value ? Commands are not necessary. You just need to bind a property to store the selected item

Comment: @nidarshanifernando if you really use MVVM and bind `ItemsSource` to some list then `SelectedItem(s)` will be of the same type as item in your source list so if your source is `List<ItemClass>` then `SelectedItem(s)` will be of `ItemClass` type and if you bind `SelectedItem` property it should be bound to `ItemClass` property in your view model

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `SelectedItem` property is the type of the item objects that you have added to the `Items` or `ItemsSource` collection. If you have for example bound the `ItemsSource` property to a collection of strings, `SelectedItem` will return one of these strings, like:

```
var selectedItem = (string)cb.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do this without resorting to code behind.  Here is an example how:

Expose your ViewModel as DataContext for the form in the code behind constructor.  Something like:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _vm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var vm = new MainWindowViewModel
            {
                People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(new List<Person>
                {
                    new Person {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"},
                    new Person {FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe"}
                })
            };

            vm.Commit += (sender, args) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You selected: " + _vm.SelectedPerson.FirstName);
            };

            DataContext = vm;
            _vm = vm;
        }
    }
```

In the XAML, bind the `ItemsSource` to the view model `ObservableCollection` and its `SelectedItem` property to the view model Selected... property like so:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding CommitSelection}">Click Me</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

See the `TextBlock` at `Grid.Row="1"`  I am binding whatever selected there.
Also, see the `Button` `Command`... I am binding that to an ICommand that is itself when called will call the `Commit` event handler that is bound to the code behind (see `vm.Commit += ...`) in the code behind.

And finally, here is the example view model code:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Person _selectedPerson;
        private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;

        public event EventHandler Commit;

        public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return _selectedPerson; }
            set { _selectedPerson = value; RaisePropertyChange("SelectedPerson"); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> People
        {
            get { return _people; }
            set { _people = value; RaisePropertyChange("People"); }
        }

        public ICommand CommitSelection
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<object>(o =>
                {
                    if (Commit != null) Commit(this, new EventArgs());
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure you are familiar with `INotifyPropertyChange` and `RelayCommand` patterns so I'll leave those out. Basically the viewmodel is implementing `ViewModelBase` which implement the `INotifyPropertyChange` helper function (`RaisePropertyChange`).  And my `RelayCommand<T>` is basically just glue code to glue the `EventHandler` to the `ICommand`. And the `Person` model class is basically a POCO with `FirstName` and `LastName` string property.